# Is it possible to resize the checkbox of checklist box in asp .net?

Tags: c#, checklistbox

I have a `CheckListBox`, I want to resize the check box it will hold. My first question is, is it possible to resize the checkbox (I want to make it slimmer), if yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that. Have a look [this](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html). You should be able to get an idea.